# how to upload image file and display using express nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload

I have used following code :

fileupload.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/file_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

fileupload.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');

//console.log(multer);

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(multer({ dest: '/tmp/'}));

app.get('/fileupload.html', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "fileupload.html" );
})

app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {

   console.log(req.files.file.name);
   console.log(req.files.file.path);
   console.log(req.files.file.type);

   var file = __dirname + "/" + req.files.file.name;
   fs.readFile( req.files.file.path, function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
         if( err ){
              console.log( err );
         }else{
               response = {
                   message:'File uploaded successfully',
                   filename:req.files.file.name
              };
          }
          console.log( response );
          res.end( JSON.stringify( response ) );
       });
   });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

I have used these above code for file uploading But when excute using node fileupload.js in terminal i am getting type error `TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');`

Can any one help to resolved this problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're trying to use `multer`'s old API. It changed awhile back, see the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/) for more information.

In your particular case of uploading a single file, you would remove the `app.use(multer({ ... }))` line and instead use `.single()` and `req.file` like:

```
var upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp/'});

// File input field name is simply 'file'
app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  var file = __dirname + '/' + req.file.filename;
  fs.rename(req.file.path, file, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(500);
    } else {
      res.json({
        message: 'File uploaded successfully',
        filename: req.file.filename
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much mscdex .File uploaded successfully

Comment: @SunilGarg Make sure you're sending your image in a field called "file" when you post to your server...

Comment: How can i store image path in database table (MySQL)

Answer (score 4):

**Multer** adds a body object and a file or files object to the request object. The body object contains the values of the text fields of the form, the file or files object contains the files uploaded via the form.

Use this code, hope this will help you.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
var upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp' })

app.get('/fileupload.html', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "fileupload.html" );
})

app.post('/file_upload', upload.single("file"), function (req, res) {
   var file = __dirname + "/" + req.file.originalname;
   fs.readFile( req.file.path, function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
         if( err ){
              console.error( err );
              response = {
                   message: 'Sorry, file couldn\'t be uploaded.',
                   filename: req.file.originalname
              };
         }else{
               response = {
                   message: 'File uploaded successfully',
                   filename: req.file.originalname
              };
          }
          res.end( JSON.stringify( response ) );
       });
   });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Comment: This solution also worked file uploading issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

The above solution doesn't worked for me so I have used storage method:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.htm" );
})


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var ext = require('path').extname(file.originalname);
        ext = ext.length>1 ? ext : "." + require('mime').extension(file.mimetype);
        require('crypto').pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
            cb(null, (err ? undefined : raw.toString('hex') ) + ext);
        });
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/file_upload', upload.any(), function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.files);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me correctly

```js
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    formidable = require('formidable'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp/'});
var app = express();


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('leistening on port', server.address().port);
})

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  var file = 'uploads' + '/' + req.file.originalname;
  fs.rename(req.file.path, file, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(500);
    } else {
      res.json({
        message: 'File uploaded successfully',
        filename: req.originalname
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="title">
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
                
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems that it's not safe to keep original file name or extension and I found/made this code for displaying images directly everywhere by adding .jpg to your file url:

```
restapi.get('/uploads/:id', function (req, res) {
  var storedMimeType = 'image/jpeg';
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', storedMimeType)
 fs.createReadStream(path.join('./uploads/', req.params.id).replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")).pipe(res)
})
```