# How to upload an image using node.js+mysql+express?

Tags: mysql, node.js, image, express, upload

I am new to Node.js ,with the help of [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm)
tutorial I've learned how to write REST API using Node.js .Can anybody please help me to understand how to upload an image file using Node.js and saving it in mysql table ? I've been searching for it , but couldn't get something useful . Any help would be useful to me.

Comment: I found the answer in another post , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477145/how-to-upload-image-file-and-display-using-express-nodejs)

Answer (score 2):

Typically files are uploaded as multipart form data from a web page. You could start there with a simple `<input type="file">` on a web page.

Create an endpoint in Express, and consider a package to help parse it. One like [express-formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable) would be a good start. Then you will have the file from the request.

To save to mysql, I'd suggest the package knexjs. This is a nice library to programmatically write SQL queries. You'll have to define your own tables that store the image (probably as BLOBs) and you can use Knex to store the new images into your DB.

Be aware of the asynchronous flow in NodeJS. For your Express endpoints, you only want to finish the response after the DB code is done, like inside the knex call's callback (or at the final `.then()` of a promise chain)